# Rails3 custom controller method not routed: works in Rails2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, custom-routes

I've been using Rails 2.3.8 for a project that I've been working on, but have just migrated the project over to Rails 3.0.3.  After ironing out the basic bugs, I've got a problem now with a custom controller method.

In the gallery_controller, I had a custom method called 'extract'.  In rails 2.3.8, this worked fine, no extra configuration.  I could go to /galleries/extract/:id and it would do what I wanted it to.

Now that code breaks the app when I try to create a link to it with the original code in the form:

```
<%= link_to "Add photos to gallery from: ",
        :action => 'extract', :id => @gallery.id %>
```

and the error I get when I try to go to the page with this code on it:

```
No route matches {:action=>"extract", :controller=>"galleries", :id=>2}
```

After looking at routes.rb, I've come to suspect that this fails because the

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

is not included, and is in fact deprecated.

Running rake tasks | grep 'extract' gives me nothing.

So how should I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Routing Guide: Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). You need to tell your application's routes about the extract action, with something like this:

```
resources :gallery do
  get 'extract', :on => :member
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That helped a lot.